# Unit test AngularJs $resource query with params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I would like to know how to unit test AngularJs $resource query with params.

I have this:

**services.js**

```
angular.module('conciergeApp.services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Reply', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/reply/:id/');
    });
```

**controllers.js**

```
conciergeControllers.controller('ReplyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Reply',
    function($scope, Reply) {

        $scope.hotel_replies = Reply.query({
            hotel: $scope.hotel_id
        });
    }
]);
```

So, the API Endpoint that gets queried here is:

```
'/api/reply/?hotel=<hotel_id>'

// aka

'/api/reply/?hotel=1'
```

This works when manually tested, but how do you unit test this?

With `Jasmine spyOn`, or `$httpBackend`.  Whichever would be fine?

Can this be used?  I tried this pattern, but couldn't do it successfully:

```
spyOn(object, 'method').andCallFake(function({foo:bar}) {
  return myMockObject
});
```

Comment: There are several bits to your system here. Which part are you trying to unit test? Do you want to check that your controller makes the correct call on the Reply service, or do you want to check that the Reply service is using $resource as expected, or do you want to check that $resource works?

Comment: @dst I'd like to check that the `controller` is making the correct call with the specified params `?hotel__isnull=True`, and that `$resource` works.

Comment: I don't think you need to check that $resource is working - it is an external dependency from angular that you can assume is unit tested before being published. You can concentrate on unit testing your own code.

Comment: Good point @dst. Updated my answer to include doing a unit test against Reply that asserts that $resource has been initialized correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4bum001r/4/) using Jasmine 2.0 and htmlRunner. Explanation to follow:

So inside your ReplyCtrl unit test:

```
describe('ReplyCtrl Controller', function () {
    var Reply;
    var ReplyCtrl;
    var $scope;
    var ReplyQueryMock;
    var HOTEL_ID = 1234;
    beforeEach(module('conciergeApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_Reply_, $controller, $rootScope) {
        // This object can be used throughout your controller unit test for the
        // response of calling the Reply.query method
        ReplyQueryMock = {};
        Reply = _Reply_;
        spyOn(Reply, 'query').and.returnValue(ReplyQueryMock);
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $scope.hotel_id = HOTEL_ID;
        ReplyCtrl = $controller('ReplyCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
    }));

    it('should populate hotel_replies', function () {
        expect(Reply.query).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            hotel: HOTEL_ID
        });
        expect($scope.hotel_replies).toBe(ReplyQueryMock);
    });
});
```

This will mock out your Reply service and return a mocked object for the query. You will verify that your $scope's `hotel_replies` is the result of calling Reply.query with the `hotel_id` that is present on $scope.

**Edit:** Presumably $resource has been unit tested for you (by Angular team!). You might just want to verify that you setup the resource with the correct URL rather than digging down into the internals of what $resource really does (like calling $http for example). Fiddle link above updated, and would look something like the following:

```
describe('Reply Resource', function () {
    var Reply;
    var $resource;
    var ReplyResourceMock;
    beforeEach(module('conciergeApp.services', function ($provide) {
        // Mock out $resource here
        $provide.factory('$resource', function () {
            ReplyResourceMock = {};
            var $resource = jasmine.createSpy('$resource');
            $resource.and.returnValue(ReplyResourceMock);
            return $resource;
        });
    }));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_Reply_, _$resource_) {
        Reply = _Reply_;
        $resource = _$resource_;
    }));

    it('should initialize resource', function () {
        expect($resource).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/api/reply/:id/');
        expect(Reply).toBe(ReplyResourceMock);
    });
});
```

*From original answer, probably overkill since you use $resource to abstract $http (still shown in fiddle)*

<strike>Then to verify $resource works correctly from your Reply factory/service, you will want to inject $httpBackend. You can verify that the proper REST endpoint is called with the correct data.</strike>